# how to wrap text around a :before pseudoelement?

Tags: html, css

As the title says - how do I wrap text around a pseudoelement? See example below:

```css
.area {
    position: relative;
}

.area:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/sprites/new_packs/181501-interface.png');
    background-position: 7px -278px;
}
```

```html
<div class="area">
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
</div>
```

I did some preliminary research and found this answer:

[Getting H1 text to wrap beside a ::before pseudo element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27909313/getting-h1-text-to-wrap-beside-a-before-pseudo-element)

Adding a `float: left;` does not work:

```css
.area {
    position: relative;
}

.area:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;

    /*SO answer #1*/
    float: left;

    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/sprites/new_packs/181501-interface.png');
    background-position: 7px -278px;
}
```

```html
<div class="area">
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
</div>
```

Is this even possible? If so - how best do I go about accomplishing it?

Comment: That is because the `position:absolute`. That takes out of the flow of the document. The `float` does — not — know about the `:before` then.

Comment: simply remove absolute position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there, just remove the `position: absolute` from your second attempt.

Answer (score 2):

remove `position: absolute;` from `css`

```css
.area {
  position: relative;
}

.area:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  //position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  /*SO answer #1*/
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/sprites/new_packs/181501-interface.png');
  background-position: 7px -278px;
}
```

```html
<div class="area">
  <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
</div>
```

Comment: becasue there is no need for such easy and obivious thing ... by the way you can edit his answer to add the code